# Headers error, css/bootstrap issues

Tags: php, header, console, bootstrapping

First of all,here is my file-data "structure":

[image]

Inside css folder there is a file estilos.css, but theres something wrong. My program works porperly but if i use the inspect elemnt i got some error. Take a look:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Hope you can help me!

Comment: Does the file estilos.css exist in the css directory?

Comment: Yeah mate, take a look:
https://i.gyazo.com/a2eadcbadd51094154e9471924a386c6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you have a css file whose name is **estilos**  rather than **estilos.css**.
As you pointed out in the image at https://i.gyazo.com/a2eadcbadd51094154e9471924a386c6.png

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/a2eadcbadd51094154e9471924a386c6.png]

Rename the file to estilos.css and you will not get the error anymore.

Also change your code from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css">
```

To

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
```

The ../ is not required

Comment: I've changed it, take a look:
https://i.gyazo.com/787fbb2d4baf51fbb88033042778d7b6.png
But it does not fix anything :/

Comment: Make a hard reload in your browser (in case of chrome press [ctrl]+[shift]+[r]) in case of firefox press [ctrl]+[F5]

Comment: Check the updated answer as the css folder is right next to the PHP file you do not need to use ../

Comment: No way mate, nothing has changed :S

Comment: that's strange even after following the steps from the answer and a hard reload.. it should work

Comment: This is really annoying pal, dont know what to do:/

Comment: What is the file you are trying to run in your browser, and are you using a web address something like http://localhost/something/ or file:///

Comment: Yeah mate, im using MAMP and i go to localhost, then to the name of the folder which contains my files. Finally i click on my hola.php file (which is my index.php)

Comment: I got this error now:
https://i.gyazo.com/72bdd6f2aaabbca383567ed7a848f0a7.png
https://i.gyazo.com/996728af263d812390b89ce8aa9d3baa.png

Comment: Can't see the image

Comment: Man that is a url not an error how can a url be an error.. There must be something more to it?

Comment: That is beacuse you have a space in your directory name `Martin Gabriel` Which should never be done over the web.
use names like martin_gabriel and the error will be gone

Comment: That will be gone if you remove `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css">` and put in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">` as i said in my answer